# A superposition theorem question

Tags: dc

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDAweK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a problem from the image. According to superposition theory, I tried to find total resistance of V2 source in order to calculate current, also I have no idea how to do the current divider rule to find current through R2 Please guide me the answer of the question, thank you.

I tried to find the current through R2:
R(1v)=100+56*27/(56+27)=118.2 ohms.
Finding total current from V1 source first.
1V/118.2=8.46 mA.
I used current divider rule on 1V side voltage source:
27/(56+27)*8.46mA =2.75 mA.

R(1.5V)=56+100*27/(100+27)= 77.26 ohm
1.5V/77.26 ohm= 19.41 ohm
Then I have problem in applying current divider rule to find current through R2.
100/(100+56+27)*19.41= 10.6 mA
The method of applying the rule is still unclear, so I have the question.

Comment: Please include your attempt at a solution in your post.

Comment: There is a circuit editor Ctrl-M...

Answer (score 1):

Are you asked to use superposition for this problem ?

I found that if you use KVL for the two loops (left and right) you can solve it fairly quick.

Comment: I was asked to use superposition theory but I had issue on the current calculation on the 1.5V voltage source.

Comment: once you removed V1, there is only one current going through R2,   i2= 1.5/56 = 26.78 mA